# Uninstalling Perl Error: Cannot remove due to the following packages that depend on it

Tags: perl

I'm trying to upgrade my version of Perl from 5.14 up to 5.20.

When I run the perl 5.20 upgrade sudo pkg update `system/runtime/perl@5.20` I get this error:

```
pkg update: No matching version of system/runtime/perl can be installed:
  Reject:  pkg://ms.system.com/system/runtime/perl@5.20.0,5.11-0.151006:20140604T182727Z
  Reason:  This version is excluded by installed incorporation pkg://perl.system.com/omniti/incorporation/perl-514-incorporation@5.14,5.11-0.151002:20120725T211507Z
```

Thus I'm trying to uninstall the current 5.14 version first with `sudo pkg uninstall system/incorporation/perl-514-incorporation` and got:

```
Creating Planpkg uninstall: Cannot remove 'pkg://perl.omniti.com/omniti/incorporation/perl-514-incorporation@5.14,5.11-0.151002:20120725T211507Z' due to the following packages that depend on it:
// A list of dependent packages
```

Any idae on how to get pass this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *strongly* recommend that you don't attempt to upgrade your system perl. A lot of miscellaneous stuff in your OS depends on it and upgrading it to a new major version will entail breaking a lot of stuff. Consider also that this upgrade will require rebuilding every CPAN module with XS dependencies as well.

The better solution is to use [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/) to install perl-5.20.0 locally in your home directory. You can then use that to work with newer perls without touching your OS perl.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I brought that up to the higher ups and they told me to just put a hold on it until management rolls the servers. I basically said what you said and it made me sound smart. Thanks for the input.